# NWSWindow events sequence when NSWindow closes?

Tags: cocoa, monomac

Can Anyone give a list of NWSWindow events sequence when NSWindow closes. More specifically which is the last notification that a NSWindow that closes sends. Apple docs are very sparse on any sequence stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The messages sent to a window when closing are – windowShouldClose: and – windowWillClose:. These are sent to the window's delegate and conform to the [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillReturnFieldEditor%3atoObject%3a) protocol.
Also you can register to receive [NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSWindow)'s notifications such as NSWindowWillCloseNotification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowWillCloseNotification:) name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:self.window];

- (void)windowWillCloseNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // ... do something, save information...
    NSWindow *window = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:window];
}
```

Comment: I already know that - it is just that this is not right, because when a NSWindow which is key for example is closed it does receive a didResignKey after receiving windowWillClose. So that is why I ask for the last message an NSWindow receives as part of the event sequence. In Windows I can tell you the last one is WM_DESTROY - in Cocoa - maybe only god knows.